# Django updating in bulk based on filter

Tags: django

I have this simple query where I want to update more than 1 record based on a filter but I get an error from MySql complaining on some limits that I didn't placed:

```
Tag.objects.filter( definition__isnull = True ).filter( name__in = tags ).update(
    definition = "We have no description for this tag"
)
```

`tags` is an array of tag names. The error I get is: `NotSupportedError: (1235, "This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'")`

Comment: Which MySQL version are you using?

Comment: Django supports MySQL 5.0.3 and higher.

Comment: I just installed mysql 5.7 and I get the same error message. I can't understand where the limit is being placed.